# Prevent scroll on spacebar press inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on the webpage with an iframe embedded that has a game which requires pressing a spacebar to start it. The game can be found at http://simpleqode.com/preview/sandbox/yearbook/14/ (under the Thanks section).

The problem is that when the iframe is focused and I press a spacebar - the page scrolls further down. Below is what I added to disable it:

```
    $(window).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This has been added both on the main  page and the iframe. Everything works great in latest Chrome, however doesn't work in Edge. To reproduce this please open Edge, scroll down to the game, focus on it and press spacebar - the page will scroll down, although this functionality was prevented with the code above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `e.preventDefault()` work?

Comment: @Isaac, no. I've tried both `return false` and `e.preventDefault`. When the iframe is focused - those rules get ignored.

Comment: You can't access the inside of a cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*. When focused the event occurs inside the new window created by the iframe

Comment: @charlietfl, I added the js code to the contents of the iframe itself.

Comment: @charlietfl, yes. They are in the same folder on my side.

Comment: try keydown instead of keyup and use e.keyCode instead of which. Hope this will help

Comment: @MarouenMhiri, great advice! using keydown instead of keyup on the iframe part solved the issue. I think this was important to cancel the scoll before anything else happened.

Comment: Cheers! glad this could help! this is a great reading if interested : https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html